# I don't want install a Bootstrapper Project itself

Tags: wix, bootstrapper, burn

I am using VS2012+WiX3.9.
Now, I assume the name of WiX Bootstrapper Project as MyBundle.
I want to install Sample1.msi and Sample2.msi by this project.
When I carry out MyBundle.exe, MyBundle is installed other than Sample1 and Sample2.
I want to only install Sample1 and Sample2 and I don't want to install MyBundle.
Is it possible? If possible, how should I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can use the MsiPackage@Visible attribute to have Sample1 and Sample2 show in Programs and Features, WiX doesn't support not showing the Bundle in Programs and Features. See:  [Option to hide burn ARP entry](http://wixtoolset.org/issues/4159/)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. Burn is a package manager, too, not just a bootstrapper, downloader, bundler, chainer and reboot handler.

If you do use it, you can learn to take advantage of the package manager features.